# Selenium Error: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am experimenting with Selenium (3.141.0) using Python 3.7 and chromedriver (2.45.615291) and am getting the following error.

`TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'.`

Main code:

```
from session import browser
from authentication import consolelogin as cl
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

#select driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome

#define options for session
options = Options()
options.set_headless(False)
options.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy","none")
options.binary_location = "file_location" 

#create a session object
session = browser.session(driver=driver,options=options)
session.launch()

#login to google
Google = cl.GoogleLogin("https://accounts.google.com","username"
,"password",session.driver)
Google.UserLogin()
```

Which creates a browser session using the following code:

```
class session():
    def __init__(self,driver,options):
        self.__name = "BrowserSession"
        self.driver = driver
        self.options = options        

    def launch(self):
        driver = self.driver(options=self.options)
        return driver
```

Which then uses the session to attempt a login:

```
class site():
    def __init__(self,url,username,password):
        self.url=url
        self.username=username
        self.password=password

class GoogleLogin(site):
    def __init__(self,url,username,password,session):
        site.__init__(self,url,username,password)
        self.session = session

    def UserLogin(self):
        now = self.session.get(self.url) #go to site
        #perform the login
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the initialised driver returned from `session.launch()` and pass that to `GoogleLogin` instead of `session.driver` which is the still uninitialised driver:

```
driver = session.launch()

Google = GoogleLogin("https://accounts.google.com", "username", "password", driver)
```